# How to Compare Numbers On Separate Objects?

Tags: apex, formula-field

I have one criteria to check the value match:

> user.code__c = 4 (Formula with datatype as number and decimal is 0 )

I run the below code in developer console:

```
system.debug([select code__c from user Limit 1].code__c) 
//Output -> 4
```

But I run the same in batch and used debug its showing 4.0

So my batch condition failed.

When I see the record detail page and there it shows as 4.

What would be the reason?

How am i checking the criteria ?

```
Criteria value = criteriaObj.Value__c //which is mentioned as 4
//After changing above record value from 4 to 4.0 then it goes fine.
userFieldValue = string.valueOf(userObj.get('Code__c'));
if(criteriaValue == userFieldValue )
{
  criteriapassed =true;
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify how you are checking that criterion in your batch?

Comment: 4 does equal 4.0. The only thing I'd be concerned about is if it's not *exactly* 4.0 (say, 4.0000000001, which would round to 4.0).

Comment: updated. but 4.0 is matched now.

Comment: As per my understanding number is a decimal  right ?

Comment: @sfdcfoc The only thing I'd be concerned about is if it's not exactly 4.0 (say, 4.0000000001, which would round to 4.0)  wondering ?

Answer (score 1):

The datatype of a numeric field is double, so you need to parse it. You can use Integer.valueOf();

For example:

```
Criteria value = criteriaObj.Value__c //which is mentioned as 4
//After changing above record value from 4 to 4.0 then it goes fine.
userFieldValue = string.valueOf(Integer.valueOf(userObj.get('Code__c')));
if(criteriaValue == userFieldValue )
{
  criteriapassed =true;
}
```

Comment: I have convert those into string than integer(generic way). Any way upvoted. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should consider adding this follet to you're query locator. It's hard to determine the mechanics or feasibility of that based on what you've shared so far.

If you keep the logic where it is, don't compare strings. Compare numbers.

```
if (criteriaObj.Value__c == userObj.Code__c)
    // do stuff
```

If you really feel compelled to compare strings, you can at least set the scale to strip out decimal places, but you must first check null.

```
public static String getIntegerRepresentation(Decimal value)
{
    return (value == null) ? null : String.valueOf(value.setScale(0));
}

// later...

String criteria = getIntegerRepresentation(criteriaObj.Value__c);
String value = getIntegerRepresentation(userObj.Codee__c);
if (criteria == value)
    // do stuff
```